# Apple Keystore file for applications

Tags: ios, iphone, keystore

I was wondering is it possible to create key store file for ios applications. To download app from store it costs 1 USD.

I wanted to allow some people to download it over store without paying. Primarlt for testing.

For android is possible, I could create keys that user enters. All is explained here, but I was wondering if I could do that for apple

Links explains how to do for android:
https://headjack.io/tutorial/create-android-keystore-file/

Comment: Use TestFlight.

Comment: If your app is released you can also get promotion codes from iTunesConnect and distribute those to users to allow a free download.